# openpyxl - How to unable "freeze_panes" in .xlsx worksheet?

Tags: excel, openpyxl

I'm using openpyxl 3.0.5 on Windows with python 3.7.9.

I tried to unable it by setting '' as freeze_panes's value, but it breaks .xlsx file so it's not the answer.

```
def x(target_book):
    sheet_data = target_book[sheet_name]
    sheet_data.freeze_panes = ''
```

Please tell me how to **unable** "freeze_panes" in .xlsx worksheet.

Comment: You'll need to read about worksheet views in the OOXML specification.

Comment: Thank you for you advise, I found the answer.

Answer (score 0):

When we want to unfreeze pane, following code needed.

```
def x(target_book):
    sheet_data = target_book[sheet_name]
    sheet_data.freeze_panes = 'A1'
    sheet_data.views.sheetView[0].selection[1] = ''
```

When freeze pane defined, xml description is like this.

```
-<sheetViews>
   -<sheetView workbookViewId="0" zoomScaleNormal="85" zoomScale="85" topLeftCell="A65" showGridLines="0">
      <pane topLeftCell="L1" state="frozen" activePane="topRight" xSplit="4"/>
      <selection sqref="A42" activeCell="A42"/>
      <selection sqref="B1:Q84" activeCell="B1" pane="topRight"/>
    </sheetView>
</sheetViews>
```

When we set 'A1' as freeze_panes, xml become like this. Pane element removed.

```
-<sheetViews>
   -<sheetView zoomScaleNormal="85" zoomScale="85" workbookViewId="0" topLeftCell="A65" showGridLines="0">
      <selection sqref="A42" activeCell="A42"/>
      <selection sqref="B1:Q84" activeCell="B1" pane="topRight"/>
   </sheetView>
</sheetViews>
```

In this xml, 2nd selection element refers to 'pane' attribute, but it's already deleted. It causes error when open this .xlsx in Excel.

So I removed 2nd selection element with following code.

```
sheet_data.views.sheetView[0].selection[1] = ''
```

I think this way is not smart, so if you have any good answer, please tell me.